# URL with at-sign is truncated

Tags: url, at-sign

Is anyone familiar with URL format like below?

```
https://www.facebook.com@www.cigital.com
```

```
https://www.facebook.com:@www.cigital.com
```

As you can see from visiting these URLs, you will be navigated to `https://www.cigital.com/` instead of `https://www.facebook.com`.

Can someone shed some light on the URL format and why the `www.facebook.com` part is truncated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an HTTP authentication scheme to send an authorization header along with a request.

```
https://<username>:<password>@domain.com
```

If no authentication required, it  is usually effectively the same as an ordinary GET request to `https://domain.com`.

A URL like `https://www.facebook.com@www.cigital.com/` looks like phishing to me; it was made to intentionally deceive someone into believing the destination was somewhere at `facebook.com` but actually led to someplace else.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax, A generic URI is of the form: 
scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]